# Where in Scripture is the Holy Spirit said to be speaking directly?

Tags: pneumatology

God the Son speaks in Luke [5:31-32](http://www.usccb.org/bible/luke/5/):

> Jesus said to them in reply, “Those who are healthy do not need a physician, but the sick do. I have not come to call the righteous to repentance but sinners.”

God the Father speaks in Mark [1:10-11](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mark/1/):

> On coming up out of the water he saw the heavens being torn open and the Spirit, like a dove, descending upon him. And a voice came from the heavens, “You are my beloved Son; with you I am well pleased.”

Paul tells, in 1Timothy [4:1-2](http://www.usccb.org/bible/1timothy/4/), of what the Spirit says:

> Now the Spirit explicitly says that in the last times some will turn away from the faith by paying attention to deceitful spirits and demonic instructions through the hypocrisy of liars with branded consciences.

...another example of this sort of speaking, in Acts [8:29](http://www.usccb.org/bible/acts/8/):

> The Spirit said to Philip, “Go and join up with that chariot.”

---

I do not have much of an issue thinking of either the Father or the Son as speaking, but I do not seem to have that same attitude towards the Holy Spirit. Obviously, the Holy Spirit speaks directly at any chosen time, that certainly is not at issue; and any differences that I see between the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit are not true differences in any merely-human sense in a way that is an absolute and glorious *mystery*, and all that I might confidently say now is that they are three distinct and divine persons. So I have the following question:

I'm not exactly looking for quotation marks like in the first two passages above, but where are the places in Scripture where the Holy Spirit is said to be speaking directly?

To clarify, when we say the Nicene Creed, we say: "He has spoken through the Prophets". I confess this, but here I am looking for something different. What are the verses that mention the "Holy Spirit" and then mark a passage of text as His words? I expect that there are a number of such verses.

I would like a pretty dry answer that looks like the first half of this question. If something is unsure or controversial, saying "might be" is fine, but please nothing too contrived, and I would not like any commentary. I would just like to know where in Scripture I may look if I would like to reflect on the manner in which the Holy Spirit speaks.

Comment: If you're searching the Scriptures for for where the Spirit is speaking you are missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: Also, are you certain that it is _the Father_ who is speaking in Mark 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course there are many specific occurrences of the Spirit speaking in the Bible. All prophecy and scripture is the Spirit speaking. **Thus says the Lord, is the same as thus says the Spirit.**

> And coming to us, he took Paul’s belt and bound his own feet and hands and said, **“Thus says the Holy Spirit,** ‘This is how the Jews at Jerusalem will bind the man who owns this belt and deliver him into the hands of the Gentiles.’ ” (Acts 21:11, ESV)
>
> He who has an ear, let him hear what the **Spirit says** to the churches. (Rev 2:2, ESV)
>
> Therefore, as the **Holy Spirit says**, “Today, if you hear his voice (Heb 3:7)

And many other similar references could be tallied.

With regard to the specific verse you mention, the Spirit is to ‘explicitly say’ this seems to imply more then the general inspiration of scripture but particular prophecies that speak directly to a specific situation, i.e. a horrible apostasy from the gospel in the ‘last times’.

[Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary](http://bible.cc/1_timothy/4-1.htm), conveniently identifies a few verses, the Spirit has spoken about on this particular subject.

> the Spirit-speaking by the prophets in the Church (whose prophecies rested on those of the Old Testament, Da 7:25; 8:23, &c.; 11:30, as also on those of Jesus in the New Testament, Mt 24:11-24), and also by Paul himself, 2Th 2:3 (with whom accord 2Pe 3:3; 1Jo 2:18; Jude 18).
>
> expressly-"in plain words." This shows that he refers to prophecies of the Spirit then lying before him.

The Apostles all seemed to have a clear vision of this ‘future event’ as it shows up in various locations in the Bible. ‘The Spirit speaking explicitly’ the apostle understands not a revelation made to him alone, but that the infallible Spirit of God and the Spirit of prophecy guided he and the rest of the apostles to instruct the church and prepare it for this specific future danger. **This Spirit of prophecy is the Spirit speaking.**

Comment: @Alypius - If you mean making an audible sound to human ears, I would say Jesus did most of the 'speaking' as he became human. So naturally he spoke the most and almost exclusively. But when the Father spoke in audible sounds (on rare occasions) most would think (putting it in human terms) that it is the Spirit actually making the sound which the Father is intending to say and the expression of these words is the Son. The Spirit is the immediate present perfecter and working presence of God -he does the immediate works of the Trinity, including any miraculous sounds.

Answer (score 4):

[Acts 10:19](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Act&c=10&v=1&t=KJV#conc/19)

Greek text of Stephanus 1550:

> τοῦ δὲ Πέτρου ἐνθυμουμένου περὶ τοῦ ὁράματος εἶπεν αὐτῷ τὸ πνεῦμα Ἰδού, ἄνδρες τρεῖς ζητοῦσιν σε

English translation:

> While Peter thought about the vision, the Spirit said to him, "Behold, three men seek you."

Answer (score 4):

the Holy Spirit said, "Set apart for me Barnabas and Saul for the work to which I have called them."  (Acts 13:2)

Answer (score 1):

**Hebrews 10:15, 16, 18**

> The Holy Spirit also testifies to us about this. First he says:
>
> "This is the covenant I will make with them after that time, says the
>   Lord. I will put my laws in their hearts, and I will write them on
>   their minds.”
>
> Then he adds: “Their sins and lawless acts I will remember no more.”
>   And where these have been forgiven, sacrifice for sin is no longer
>   necessary.

Comment: What reasons do you have to think that those things are said exclusively by the Holy Spirit? Because those quotations are from Jeremiah. I'm not sure we should take it to mean that they're exclusively spoken by the Spirit just because it comes about a sentence saying the Spirit testifies to us.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no spirit has any physical form ( either holy or evil), which means we can't see spirits with our naked eyes. And for both the good and the evil spirits to speak, physical beings have to be possessed by them. Besides, The Holy Spirit is the Spirit of God. When God speaks, the Holy Spirit speaks and when the Holy Spirit speaks, God speaks.
Remember this however that it was only Jesus who saw the dove descending, the heaven opening, and the voice saying "This is my beloved son..." It was not specifically confirmed whose voice it was. Maybe the same Holy Spirit that was descending in form of a Dove was also the One speaking from heaven, no one knows.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  If you'd like to strengthen your answer, I'd recommend adding sources to show that this analysis isn't just your own, but that it reflects the views of some Christian tradition or denomination.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).